# CSS not selector and :hover

Tags: html, css

I am confused by :hover and more confused by the not selector, I am self taught so that could be the issue here:

I think the :hover defines the bit of the page or site that the mouse rolls over, to activate it.

I have been trying to use the :not pseudo class to not select part of a lnk but select the rest of it.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Varta', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  border-right: 5px solid #0966C2;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav a {
  color: #0966C2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0966C2;
  /* Why won't this css below not select the i(icon)   tag and select the rest re the links Home My Network etc. I am trying to replace the lines above*/
  /*nav a:hover :not(i)  {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0966C2;
}*/
}

nav a:hover i {
  color: #F3BA64;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Network</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-handshake" aria-hidden="true"></i> Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> Messaging</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notifications</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What parts of the links do you want to change to what color on hover?

Comment: I want to select the text inside the <a> tags and color them but not thet icons which are also in the <a> tag. i realised now that i need to move an element back to the <li> tag then nav li:hover :not(i) works before I was not selecting an element and thought that would select the text but was very wrong

Comment: I am sorry if my question is badly worded i just wanted to select the links re home etc using a not selector as not using the most obious a:hover as it selects the <i> tags and colours them as well I did not want to overide just not affect in the first plae

Answer (score -1):

If you want to target all `<i>` inside not hovered `<a>`, you don't need a specific style, just custom styles for the hovered one `a:hover i` that will override the `a i` ones.

Now if you really want to select the not hovered ones, you can use it that way: `a:not(:hover) i`

Comment: Gald it helped. Do not forget to upvote, or choose an answer to your post! Tanks